# Smooth animation in Cocos2d for iOS

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I move a simple `CCSprite` around the screen of an iOS device using this code:

```
[self schedule:@selector(update:) interval:0.0167];

- (void) update:(ccTime) delta {
    CGPoint currPos = self.position;
    currPos.x += xVelocity;
    currPos.y += yVelocity;

    self.position = currPos;
}
```

This works however the animation is not smooth. **How can I improve the smoothness of my animation?**

My scene is exceedingly simple (just has one full-screen `CCSprite` with a background image and a relatively small `CCSprite` that moves slowly).

I've logged the ccTime delta and it's not consistent (it's almost always greater than my specified interval of 0.0167... sometimes up to a factor of 4x).

I've considered tailoring the motion in the update method to the delta time (larger delta => larger movement etc). However given the simplicity of my scene it's seems there's a better way (and something basic that I'm probably missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the default `[self scheduleUpdate]` method rather than calling it directly as you are doing, see if that makes a difference. This method is designed for what you are doing and may be smoother.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler will try to accommodate and call your selector as per your interval but if there are other processes running, it can be earlier or later (hence why the inconsistency).

Instead, multiply your xVelocity and yVelocity by delta - this should scale the velocities into a far smoother motion.

For example:

```
- (void) update:(ccTime) delta {
    CGPoint currPos = self.position;
    currPos.x += (xVelocity * delta);
    currPos.y += (yVelocity * delta);

    self.position = currPos;
}
```

Comment: Using delta is the approach taken in the tutorials as well. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_2._your_first_game

Comment: I tried the delta approach. Unfortunately it didn't work. Using `scheduleUpdate` as suggested by andrewx worked well.